# Save multiple sheets as one pdf, excluding some sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Very novice VBA coder, I have manged through a lot of trail and error create a code to
save multiple sheets as seperate pdf:s excluding some sheets.
Now I want to copy that code and adjust it so I can also have a macro that saves all sheets to one singel PDF and excluding some sheets the same way.
This is my current code,

```
Sub LoopSheetsSaveAsPDF()
 'Create variables
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 'Loop through all worksheets and save as individual PDF in same folder
 
 'as the Excel file
 
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 
 Select Case ws.Name
 Case "Mall", "Grunddata"
 ''/// ignore these sheets
 Case Else
 ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & ws.Name & ".pdf"
 End Select
 Next ws
 
End Sub
```

I cant find the part i the code that specify it should be saved as multiple pdf:s or only one.

Would be very thankful for all help.

BR
Fredrik

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```vb
Sub LoopSheetsSaveAsPDF()
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet, repl As Boolean, n As Long
    
    repl = True 'first sheet selection replaces any previous selection
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       Select Case ws.Name
           Case "Mall", "Grunddata"
               ''/// ignore these sheets
           Case Else
               ws.Select Replace:=repl
               repl = False 'subsequent sheets get added
       End Select
    Next ws
 
    If Not repl Then 'got at least one sheet?
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
           Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/AllSheets.pdf"
    End If
End Sub
```